# Plugin (SyncDB) issue breaking site and unable to do anything

Tags: craft3, plugins

I was in the process of setting up the [UNION co SyncDB](https://plugins.craftcms.com/sync-db) plugin and must have misconfigured something as I now get the following error: "Undefined index: skipTables" and seem to be completely locked out of both the admin and site.

This is the first time I've encountered something like this where I got completely locked out (I would have assumed I'd be able to still access admin to disable the plugin manually) and now have no idea how to disable the plugin and either load the site or get into admin.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you haven't already I would post an issue over on their GitHub https://github.com/unionco/craft-sync-db/issues

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the easiest way to address this issue is to remove the dependency from your composer.json file and to then run

```
composer update
```